# attempting to pick up Object in unity is invisible but collider box can be seen

Tags: unity-game-engine, gameobject, collider

For some reason, in my game, i am able to pick up every object i want except my Oar prefab.

It shows in the editor scene that the object is picked up but is invisible, all i can see is the collider box and outlines

When i pick up the sword, it appears in my hand.  As you can see, the Oar image is on the ground however, the collider box is in the player hands.[image]

I am trying to make it look like my sword.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Your object sea to consist only of a collider ... there is no renderer component so ... nothing is rendered at the position of the object ... In other words with the information you give us it is pretty hard to tell why something isn't visible

Comment: I added new image,the gameobject was a parent object of the paddle, that only consisted of a collider.  I used the gameobject to be able to position the location of the point of where i wanted it to be held by the hand.

Comment: Could you check the render queues of your materials? It seems like your background is rendered on top of your sword ...

Comment: what does render on top of sword mean?  the sword does not overlapped.  I need to definitely scale it down in my players hands though

Comment: In Unity there are certain render queues (basically they are just indices). The higher the index the later an object is rendered. It might be the case that your background object's material has a higher render queue then your sword object and therefore the sword is rendered first, then the background on top of it -> overlaying the sword. See e.g. this post http://answers.unity.com/answers/1646494/view.html

Answer (score 0):

If im not mistaken, there is a box collider on both the GameObject(parent) and the model(child). You could try removing the collider for the parent or the child, as having a collider for both might result in some weird behaviour.